# What does pynotify.init stand for?

Tags: python, pynotify

I haven't find a documentation about pynotify, so I don't know what pynotify.init() function stands for.

Comment: Did you read this?  http://download.gna.org/py-notify/reference/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are talking about the python wrapper for libnotify

the notify.init() just wrap the C function notify_init() which initializes the notifications library.

For more examples check this: http://roscidus.com/desktop/node/336

the code source is here : http://www.galago-project.org/downloads.php

the C API : http://www.galago-project.org/docs/api/libnotify/notify_8h.html

and the ubuntu Guideline : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines#How%20do%20I%20get%20these%20slick%20icons

Update:

Here is the hole code in C from the source:

```
 /**
 * notify_init:
 * @app_name: The name of the application initializing libnotify.
 *
 * Initialized libnotify. This must be called before any other functions.
 *
 * Returns: %TRUE if successful, or %FALSE on error.
 */
gboolean
notify_init(const char *app_name)
{
    GError *error = NULL;
    DBusGConnection *bus = NULL;

    g_return_val_if_fail(app_name != NULL, FALSE);
    g_return_val_if_fail(*app_name != '\0', FALSE);

    if (_initted)
        return TRUE;

    _app_name = g_strdup(app_name);

    g_type_init();

    bus = dbus_g_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &error);

    if (error != NULL)
    {
        g_message("Unable to get session bus: %s", error->message);
        g_error_free(error);
        return FALSE;
    }

    _proxy = dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name(bus,
                                       NOTIFY_DBUS_NAME,
                                       NOTIFY_DBUS_CORE_OBJECT,
                                       NOTIFY_DBUS_CORE_INTERFACE);
    dbus_g_connection_unref(bus);

    dbus_g_object_register_marshaller(notify_marshal_VOID__UINT_STRING,
                                      G_TYPE_NONE,
                                      G_TYPE_UINT,
                                      G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_INVALID);

    dbus_g_proxy_add_signal(_proxy, "NotificationClosed",
                            G_TYPE_UINT, G_TYPE_INVALID);
    dbus_g_proxy_add_signal(_proxy, "ActionInvoked",
                            G_TYPE_UINT, G_TYPE_STRING,
                            G_TYPE_INVALID);

    _initted = TRUE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

so basically what it's does it initalisaing the D-BUS for communication and add some signals to it.

Comment: it say that pynotify.init() initialize pynotify but it doesn't say what mean initialize pynotify :-\

Comment: @xRobot: i just updated my answer , for more detail you can check the hole code from the source code from the link above.